# Using a loop to send customized emails to multiple recipients in Python

Tags: python, email

I am writing code to send customized emails to multiple recipients using the same html template. The code extracts information from a csv file.

However,  am unable to loop through the recipients to send them the email one by one. This is what I have:

```
email_list = [abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com, ghi@gmail.com]

email['from'] = 'Zoya Aqib'
for recipient in email_list:
    email['to'] = recipient
email['subject'] = 'Corporate Rating Quiz'


for index,row in df.iterrows():
    email.set_content(html.substitute({'name': row['First Name'],'score': row['Score']}))
    with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com',port=587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.login('me@gmail.com','mypassword')
        smtp.send_message(email)
    print('all done!')
```

But I am getting this error "ValueError: There may be at most 1 to headers in a message"

How do I loop over the recipients while customizing the template as shown above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because you haven't stored your email addresses as strings. Just enclose them in quotes and its should work.

Comment: This would surely lead to `SyntaxError`, not to `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send message to multiple recipients at once. I guess you should just send messages separately.

Since you're setting email['to'] multiple times, you should have just replaced the header and send message to the last address, but it's not what actually happened.
So IDK what the `email` is, but here is the solution that will probably work in your case:

```py
email_list = ['abc@gmail.com', 'def@gmail.com', 'ghi@gmail.com']

email['from'] = 'Zoya Aqib'
email['subject'] = 'Corporate Rating Quiz'


for index,row in df.iterrows():
    email.set_content(html.substitute({'name': row['First Name'],'score': row['Score']}))
    with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com',port=587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.login('me@gmail.com','mypassword')
        for recipient in email_list:
            if 'to' in email:
                del email['to'] 
            email['to'] = recipient
            smtp.send_message(email)
    print('all done!')
```